# How to scp via an intermediate computer

Tags: bash, ssh, scp

I am on computer A and in order to ssh into computer C I have to ssh  into computer B and then ssh from there. I have a one line bash script that does this with

```
ssh -XJ user@compB user@compC
```

How can I write a bash script to let me copy a file or files from compA to compC?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1034579

Comment: @l'L'l That looks good.  How can I make it into a configurable bash script ?

Comment: `scp` is, in some sense, just a wrapper around `ssh`; it takes the same options. `scp -XJ user@compB foo user@compC:foo`. (You may not need `-X` for the copy, unless something on the remote end uses a GUI to prompt you for a password.)

Comment: `scp -o 'ProxyJump user@compB' ...` is another alternative way to specify the same behavior provided by `-J`.

Comment: That said, this is more a [unix.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) question than a SO one, unless you have a question that's specific to scripting.

Comment: @Anush, nothing in your question currently says anything about what you expect around making a "configurable bash script". If you expect answers to address something, that something needs to be included in the question itself (and not already answered elsewhere -- we have preexisting Q&A describing how to parse command-line options, f/e, or how to generate a set of arguments only if a variable is non-empty; so asking about either of those things would be duplicative).

Comment: Apologies. I would like to be able to do 'copytocompC file' and it to copy that file.

Comment: Do you already have a script that does that, with the only difference being that it doesn't do the ProxyJump? That way we wouldn't need to guess at details (what destination directory, how to handle multiple arguments being passed, etc etc).

Answer (score 2):

`ProxyJump` is just as available with `scp` as it is with `ssh`; there just isn't a `-J` shortcut on all versions of the command-line tool, so you can need to spell it out the long way.

```
scp -o 'ProxyJump user@compB' ./your-local-file user@compC:/path/to/your-remote-file
```

<sub>Community Wiki since this question isn't on-topic here, and would be better suited to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)</sub>

Comment: Thank you. If I want to be able to do "copytocompC file"  how could I do that in bash?

Comment: Assuming it should copy `file` to the same remote directory every time, `compytocompC() { scp -o 'ProxyJump user@compB' "$@" user@compC:/path/to/destination/; }`?

Comment: ...the above is a function, but if you put the function body in a script it'll work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to make a server VPN on a computer B and then make an SCP from computer A to computer C using the VPN (computer B).

Otherwise, you make ssh keys from a->b and from b->c so that ssh doesn't ask you the passwords, that you make:
computer_A:$ scp -r myfilesfolder/ myuser@computerB:.
computer_A:$ ssh myuser@computerB scp -r myfilesfolder/ myuser@computerC:.

or another way is, install sshfs [look this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh)  and then you mount the folder you want to copy in computer A in computer B and after you mount the folder in computer B in computer C. After that you copy as usual the files in the mounted folder.

Comment: You don't need ssh keys from b->c; authenticating directly from a->c (with b used only at the transport layer) works fine. That's what the OP's original `ssh -J` usage does.